# jquery I am trying to append a hidden field to a hidden div from a button outside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying add to a form dynamically from a table outside the form> have a basic form and then from a summary table the form I want to click an edit button that will add elements to the form. Below is my first attempt on just adding a hidden field. I have a div that the hidden fields are in.

Here is the code below.  The table I am showing is actually in a scrollable table and div design. I stripped it down to its basic elements for this function.

```
<form id="incidentform" action="" method="get">
<div id="hidfielddiv">
    <input type="hidden" name="mchnum" value="346"/>
    <input type = "hidden" name="mchemploy" value="1"/>
    <input type = "hidden" name="persontypeid" id="persontypeid" value="2"/>    
</div>
<label class="main">Employee Information</label>
<label class="empname">Name</label>
    <label class="empname">Nursing Assistant - 80</label>
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="addincidentButton" name="addincidentButton" value="Add Incident"/>
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="display: none;">0</td>
        <td style="display: none;">2</td>
        <td>11/12/2014</td>
        <td>4:04 PM</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="button" class="editincidentbutton" value="Edit incident" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see the table is outside the form and here is the script.

```
$(function(){
    $(".editincidentbutton").click(function(){
      $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        id: 'superwitness',
        name: 'superwitness',
        value: '0'
      }).appendto("#hidfielddiv"); 
    }
    )
})
```

Comment: You have two `class` attributes in your button. The click event wont trigger because of that. Change this `class="button" class="editincidentbutton"` to this `class="button editincidentbutton"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is two-fold

1) camelcCase the appendTo function - `appendTo()`

2) you have multiple classes on your button - the first one takes precedence, so remove it
`<input type="button" class="editincidentbutton" value="Edit incident" />`

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery function name is `appendTo` with "To" capitalized, and Javascript is case-sensitive - you need to change your line of code to:

```
      }).appendTo("#hidfielddiv");
```

Comment: That alone does not fix it - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Two issues. Either do appendTo (case sensitive), or use append and reverse the divs. I wrote it below

```
$(function(){
$(".editincidentbutton").click(function(){
    $('#hidfielddiv').append('<input type="hidden" id="superwitness" name="superwitness" value="0">');
});
```

});

The second issue (important) is that the button you're listening to has two 'class' values. This should be

```
<input type="button" class="button editincidentbutton" value="Edit incident" />
```

instead of

```
<input type="button" class="button" class="editincidentbutton" value="Edit incident" />
```

I tested it and it works, let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the jQuery accessors like op stated in his example, for correct quoting and escaping, instead of inline adding the element?!